# How to use the values returned by value_counts() to do further calculations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column named `y_ocsvm` that is filled with 1 and -1 in a df named `step1`.

I used: `step1['y_ocsvm'].value_counts()` to get the counts of 1's and -1's and the output was:

```
step1['y_ocsvm'].value_counts()
Out[11]: 
 1    1622
-1     426
Name: y_ocsvm, dtype: int64
```

I would like to find the ratio of the number of -1's to the number of 1's. I could simply do 426/1622, but since I have to use this for many dataframes, the values will definitely vary which will make it difficult to calculate the same manually.

Since `value_counts()` can only be applied to pandas series, I tried doing:

```
pd.Series([step1['y_ocsvm'] == -1]).value_counts()
```

But I get the following error:

```
pd.Series([step1['y_ocsvm'] == -1]).value_counts()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-59f772263a54>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.Series([step1['y_ocsvm'] == -1]).value_counts()

  File "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 1303, in value_counts
    normalize=normalize, bins=bins, dropna=dropna)

  File "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 705, in value_counts
    keys, counts = _value_counts_arraylike(values, dropna)

  File "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 750, in _value_counts_arraylike
    keys, counts = f(values, dropna)

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_func_helper.pxi", line 348, in pandas._libs.hashtable.value_count_object

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_func_helper.pxi", line 359, in pandas._libs.hashtable.value_count_object

  File "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1816, in __hash__
    ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))

SystemError: <built-in method format of str object at 0x00000203B7063AC0> returned a result with an error set
```

I would like to know how can this be done using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do

```
step1['y_ocsvm'].value_counts()[-1] / step1['y_ocsvm'].value_counts()[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here `Series` constructor is not necessary, because `step1['y_ocsvm'] == -1` is `Series` filled by boolean values:

```
out = (step1['y_ocsvm'] == -1).value_counts()
```

For ratio is possible use:

```
print (out[True] / out[False])
```

Comment: Hey @jezrael, I just cross verified, 426/1662 = 0.2626, but when I do `out = (step1['y_ocsvm'] == -1).mean()`, the answer it gives is 0.208, which is wrong. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: What is `426` and what is `1662` ? How is count?

Comment: 426 is the number of -1's I have and 1662 is the number of +1's I have. So I have to do 426/1662. I have it in the question mentioned

Comment: So it is different, means is for 426 / (426  + 1662 )

Comment: @Junkrat - Edited answer, I think you need something else.